# How do I read .xls based rule file using kiebase instead of knowledgebase(versions 5 or less) in recent versions of drools 6+

Tags: drools

KnowledgeBase method gives an error that the method has been depricated in version of drools 6+.

Comment: That's a rather shoddy question. - Anyway, study the new API, and you'll find the answer. Otherwise, provide more information about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your problem, you are using a code similar to this (assuming xlsResource is a resource of a well-formatted decision table) :

```
KnowledgeBuilder knowledgeBuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
knowledgeBuilder.add(xlsResource, ResourceType.DTABLE, dtconf);
KnowledgeBase base = knowledgeBuilder.newKnowledgeBase();
```

And you get a message that `KnowledgeBase` is deprecated.

You should simply replace the last line by :

```
KieBase base = knowledgeBuilder.newKnowledgeBase();
```

Have a look at the API, the old `KnowledgeBase` extends `KieBase` for compatibility reasons, but is now deprecated.